# Is it possible to extract an equation from GLM or GLMM

Tags: r, glmm

Is it possible to extract an equation from a GLM or GLMM and is there any less technical information about this available? For an example of the question see code below (definitely not perfect, but it will do):

```
df <- data.frame(x=(1:300),
                 y=30*log(1:300)+30*rnorm(300, 1, 1),
                 loc=sample(1:5, 300, replace = T))

plot(df$x, df$y)
#Create model with Gaussian log link extract coefficients and create equation.
mod1 <- glm(y ~ x, family = gaussian(link = "log"), data=df)
a1 <- round(coef(mod1)[2],5)
b1 <- round(coef(mod1)[1],2)

paste0("ln(y)=",a1,"x+",b1)

#Create model containing random effects with Gaussian distribution and log link.
#But, how to include the random effects in the equation?
mod2 <- lme4::glmer(y ~ x + (1|loc), family = gaussian(link = "log"), data=df)

#Okay, no spread whatsoever, but okay.
coef(mod2)

#like this???
a2 <- round(mean(coef(mod2)$loc[,2]),5)
b2 <- round(mean(coef(mod2)$loc[,1]),2)
vara2 <- round(var(coef(mod2)$loc[,2]),5)
varb2 <- round(var(coef(mod2)$loc[,2]),2)

#Equation GLMM with variance of slope and intercept???
paste0("ln(y)=",a2,"x+",b2,"; var slope=", vara2, " var inter=", varb2)
```

Comment: You must know what the equation is, given that you set the model up, right?  Otherwise how would you know what model to enter?

Comment: Yes, but, how to incorporate the random effects in an equation? Hence, I have a model whereby the goodness of fit improves by ~40%. I want to let readers know it is by including the random effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your post includes several inaccuracies, so this is not an answer - it is just an attempt to point the inaccuracies out so that you can correct them.

1. Your second model, mod2, does not include a random slope for x, so it does not make sense to report the variance of the slope. You can however report the estimated value of the standard deviation (or variance) of the random intercept.
2. To include a random slope for x (if the values of x varied within loc), you would use a formula syntax of the form 
   y ~ 1 + x + (1 + x | loc).
   This syntax allows the random intercept and random slope to be correlated, so you can report the estimated values of the standard deviation of the random intercept, the standard deviation of the random slope of x and the correlation between the random intercept and random slope of x.
3. A formula syntax of the form 
   y ~ 1 + x + (1 + x || loc)
   allows the random intercept and random slope to be uncorrelated, so you can report the estimated values of the standard deviation of the random intercept and the standard deviation of the random slope of x.
4. Because you are using a log link in your model, you are modelling the *log expected value of y*, not the *log value of y*. Your model equation would have to reflect that and it would involve something like $log(E(y))$ rather than $ln(y)$. (To model the *log value of y*, you would have to log-transform your y values and use the identity link.)

See this article for ideas on how to report the fixed effects and a summary of the random effects structure of the model in table form: https://www.redalyc.org/pdf/2990/299023506003.pdf.

Sometimes links to articles disappear, so the article information is:

Harald Baayen, R.; Milin, Petar
Analyzing Reaction Times
International Journal of Psychological Research, vol. 3, núm. 2, 2010, pp. 12-28
Universidad de San Buenaventura
Medellín, Colombia

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the paper.

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: @A4-paper: You may be interested in this link: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/equatiomatic.html.  The link mentions the R package **equatiomatic**, which can be used currently to extract model equations for GLM models.

Comment: The link to the **equatiomatic** package is: https://github.com/datalorax/equatiomatic. The package is in its early stages of development but it's worth keeping an eye on it as its developers have plans for extending it to cover more types of models, including mixed effects models.